# "/" is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-cli

Today, I'm coding a few npm packages and a few things that need to be prepared repeatedly.

So I wanted to code a CLI to get those things done quickly.

Here is the `src/cli.js` code:

```js
export function cli(args){
  console.log(args);
}
```

Here is the `package.json` code:

```json
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A CLI to bootstrap new project",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "bin": {
    "@kensoni/my-project": "bin/my-project",
    "my-project": "bin/my-project"
  },
  "publishConfig": {
    "access": "public"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "cli"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Ken Nguyen",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "arg": "^5.0.0",
    "esm": "^3.2.25",
    "inquirer": "^8.1.1"
  }
}
```

Here is the `bin/my-project` code:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env/ node

require = require('esm')(module /*, options*/);
require('../src/cli').cli(process.argv);
```

After I execute the command `npm link` and open a new `cmd` type `my-project`, I get the following message:

```
'"/"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I am using these versions:

- node: `14.17.1`
- npm: `7.18.1`

Any ideas how it might work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove "/" after env

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

//...
```